# Can I fade in a color with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have javascript that changes some HTML with a function like this:

```
if (correct == "true") {
   $('#ft2').html('Correct');
   $('#ft2').css('color', 'Green')
   $('#ft2').css('border-color', 'Green')
} else {
   $('#ft2').html('Incorrect');
  $('#ft2').css('color', 'Red')
  $('#ft2').css('border-color', 'Red')
}
```

The text changes very quickly on the page and I would like to make it look better for my users. Is there a way that I can use jQuery to fade in the color? For example have the new color appear over the time of one second.

Comment: rather you can go for making the text `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to animate color in jquery, you'll need a plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Edit: it looks like the link to Resig's plugin is old, so you can also try some of the other plugins that have been written to do the same thing:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

here's a direct link to Resig's original plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt

Just save the page as jquery.color.js

Comment: All of the links on that page (project home, etc.) give 404 errors. The download link still works, has a version from 2007.

Comment: Ugh, you're right - I should know better than to use links from my bookmarks. I'll have to find where that thing is at and edit the link.

Comment: Even four years and a bunch of jQuery versions later, [it still seems to work](http://jsbin.com/otuva4), at least for "color" and for border colors if you specify them individually ("borderLeftColor", etc.). Background color didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird - I couldn't get animating background color to work in jsfiddle, but I can get it to work just on a regular page:

http://students.washington.edu/jamdon/color/

Answer (score 2):

If you add jQuery UI, they added support for color animations.

Read http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/ for details.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block").toggle(function() {
      $(this).animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000);
    },function() {
      $(this).animate({ color: "#00FF00" }, 1000);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#div').animate({'background-color': '#ff00ff'});
```

Comment: `$('#div').animate({'background-color': '#ff00ff'}, 1000);` need speed

Comment: For one second, use this: `$('#div').animate({'background-color': '#ff00ff'}, 1000);`

Comment: @James: It's crucial if Marife specified.

Comment: Thanks very much James. I will try this out now.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, but you're going to need a plugin to do it, Marife. JQuery's animate method only works on css properties that can be calculated in a simple manner, and color isn't one of those.

Comment: From the `animate` docs you linked: *"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated **but `background-color` cannot be**.)"* *(my emphasis)*

Comment: Exactly, which is why Resig added the color plugin.

Comment: Yes I started to realize this. I tried but it doesn't animate the colors. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Can I not just change the opacity from zero to one? What I would like is for the text and box to be invisible at first and then for it to fade into view.

Comment: Sure, just use .fadeIn() on the element you want to, well, fade in.

Comment: @user156629 - Thanks for your assistance. I think this is what I need. Now I am just trying to understand if I can fade in both things at the same time. I maybe will just ask this question and see if anyone can suggest how this could be done. My knowledge of jQuery is not so good when it comes to multiple things happening at the same time.

Comment: It will be easier to help you figure out how to do it if you show the html as well.