# jQuery - text color fade in

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I can't find a simple solution to this problem.

I am trying to fade in a color change for some text when there is an error from a button click.

```
if (document.getElementById("username").value == ""){ //First Name      
    $("#login_error").text("Please enetr a username!").css('color', '#FF0000');     
    $("#username_label").css('color', '#FF0000');fadeIn(3000);
}
```

I can get the color to change but it is instant. I am wanting to get the change of colour to fade in slowly.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320578/can-i-fade-in-a-color-with-jquery

Comment: is the ; between .css() and fadeIn() in line 3 a typo?  If not, change it to `.css().fadeIn()`

Answer (score 9):

If you add jQuery UI, they added support for color animations.

Read http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/ for details.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block").toggle(function() {
      $(this).animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000);
    },function() {
      $(this).animate({ color: "#000000" }, 1000);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

**Update:** jQuery now offers a [color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to enable only this feature without including the entire jQuery-UI library.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that.. but small plugin is still better than including the whole jQuery UI just for this small task.

Comment: You can build custom download at jquery ui page, include only UI Core and Effects Core

Comment: Cheers.  $(this).animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000); does the job!

Comment: Glad to hear it! -- don't forget to accept your favorite answers.

Comment: use https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js instead of jQuery UI

Answer (score 1):

You need to use plugin, it's not part of the built in animation: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Related question: [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 0):

of course .css call is instant, and fadeIn is just chained (started after css is changed)

try using [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate css properties using jQuery .animate function, i.e.

```
$(this).animate({ height: 250 });
```

BUT, you cannot animate color, sorry. For that you need to use plugin, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) for details.

Also, if you are using jquery UI, then it is possible:

Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.

(from http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You have sample [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

I find the method to change the color and found this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234173/1128331

already test and it work what I want to :)